# How to split a string into a vector by end of line

Tags: c++, string, vector

Hello so I'm trying to split the incoming request into a vector by line.

(example request)

```yaml
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.51
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

I want to add each line in to a vector, how can I achieve this? I've been googling around but can't seem to find an answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution would be to use a `istringstream` and `getline`.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

std::string request = ...;

std::istringstream buffer(request);
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line;
while (getline(buffer, line))
{
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```